# Push notification not taking to respective category if app is killed

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an app where I have push notification.

What I have is I go to respective category when push is clicked (from the push notification list).

All is working perfectly, except when the app is killed.

If the app is minimized and push comes, if I click on push, it goes to respective category.

However if I forcefully kill the app and push comes and click on the push, it just open the app and no transition occurs.

Is this natural behavior in iPhone or I am doing something wrong?

In `didReceiveRemoteNotification` I go to specific category based on the data I received.

Comment: Is `didReceiveRemoteNotification` getting called when you launch the previously killed app from the notification?

Comment: @Eugene : I cannot test as if I kill app, on xcode I will not get any response... **so in short, I am not sure whether it get called or not**

Comment: @Eugene : Check my answer.. this is how I solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what I used.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    if (launchOptions != nil) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dic = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
        NSMutableDictionary *dicItem = [dic objectForKey:@"aps"];
        NSString *itemNotification = [dicItem objectForKey:@"alert"];
        // do all transition here....
    }else if (launchOptions == nil){
        NSLog(@"launch ,,, nil");
    }
...//code something
}
```

Comment: Don't use `@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"` as string, there's actually a defined constant for this - `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`

Comment: @Eugene : Ohkk I will use simply UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey. But with string also it works... I will test without quotes tomorrow...

Answer (score 1):

`didReceiveRemoteNotification` not call app will not run, that time push notification open app newly in device, you manually check if any notifications are bending in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`  try this for check bending notifications in app.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

...............
...............

 UILocalNotification *localNotif =[launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) {

        NSLog(@"load notifiation *******");
        isLoadNotification=YES;
    }
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: I will check this... but how I will come to know which push I clicked if there are local notification... Lets say I have 4 notification... If I click on second notification, how I will come to know whether I clicked second or not...

Comment: sorry, Pls check localNotif details which one will call in app